# How do the Predators' Smart-Discs extend and retract?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

In the *Alien vs Predator* video games and the *AvP* and *Predator* movies, the Predators' Smart-Discs have the ability to extend and retract.

I would like to know how the Disc does this, would it be that the user has to give it a single flick of the wrist to extend it?

Answer (score 2):

Per this concept art (from the original studio designer for *Predator 2*, [Crash McCreery](https://www.stanwinstonschool.com/blog/predator-2-movie-predator-weapons)) it appears that the first "[smart-disc](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Smart-Disc)" was activated by compressing the two parts together and steered using the Predator's targeting laser.

[image: black and white concept art]

[image: Smart-disc model]

In later films and games, additional functionality has been added such as emergent blades, nano-molecular chainsaw edges and sharpened teeth. These are described as being ***mentally controlled*** (often by Predators who've earned the rank of "[Disc Master](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Disc_Master)"). As such it seems likely that they're activated using the same mental techniques.

[image: Smart-Disc as seen in the movie]